# Matplotlib and GTKAgg and OS X

Tags: python, matplotlib, macports

I installed python 2.7 and matplotlib 1.1.1 on Mountain Lion via Macports and when I run the following:

```
   import matplotlib
   matplotlib.use('GTKAgg') 
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

on the last line I get the error messages below. After looking around on the internet the only "solution" I've seen is to use 'Agg' as the backend instead of 'GTKAgg', but when I do this it runs (and terminates without any errors) but nothing plots. The lines above work fine on my Windows XP. Anyone have any suggestions?

**Error message:**

> line 2, in import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>   File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 95, in new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
>   File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/init.py", line 25, in pylab_setup globals(),locals(),[backend_name])
>   File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtkagg.py",
>   line 10, in from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtk import gtk, FigureManagerGTK, FigureCanvasGTK,\
>   File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk.py",
>   line 52, in cursors.MOVE : gdk.Cursor(gdk.FLEUR), RuntimeError: could
>   not create GdkCursor object

Comment: "but nothing plots" -- you're using `plt.show()`?

Comment: Have you tried the `MacOSX` or `CocoaAgg` backends?

Comment: Yes I am using plt.show(). I just tried the MacOSX and CocoaAgg backends. On the latter I get the plot window, but then get the following repeated over and over: **Error message:** AttributeError: 'FigureCanvasMac' object has no attribute 'restore_region'

Comment: You can get a complete list of backends to try with `import matplotlib.rcsetup as rc; print(rc.all_backends)`. It wouldn't hurt to try thim all.

Comment: It is interesting that you say you've installed Python2.7, but the error message shows files Python is running come from `Versions/2.6`. Make sure matplotlib was installed to use Python2.7, and make sure the python used to call the script is Python2.7.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I tried this with both python 2.6 and 2.7, and all the following backends (these are the possibilities mentioned in the .matplotlibrc file): ps, Qt4Agg, GTK, GTKAgg, svg, agg, cairo, MacOSX, GTKCairo, WXAgg, TkAgg, QtAgg, FltkAgg, pdf, CocoaAgg, emf, gdk, template, WX.    
Qt4Agg seems to be the only one that works consistently. However, it does not work with gtk and gobject which is how I've set up most of my animations. These use toolkit-secific GUI event handling functions such as gobject.idle_add( foo ). I get a window but nothing in it.

Comment: I should also mention that on this page:
http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Animations 

I also get the same result from the example under "Animating selected plot elements", i.e., a plot comes up but nothing in it. In that section it says "As of matplotlib-0.87, GTKAgg, TkAgg, WXAgg, and FLTKAgg support the methods discussed here."  But none of these backends work or are supported in the Macports install. For example, if I use TkAgg I get the error message "ImportError: No module named _tkagg," although I supposedly installed this variant under Macports.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `select` python27 as your primary and default python.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks all of you for your help but the matter has resolved itself with a more recent version(s) installed via a Macports update/upgrade. I'm not sure whether it was because of an update on Matplotlib, or Python, or both, but all my stuff runs OK now.